# Bar chart not drawn when chart renders

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am stuck with the following scenario as in the image below:

[highchart render issue http://cinchbusiness.com/render_prob.png](http://cinchbusiness.com/render_prob.png)

The bars do not render and leave the datalabels hanging. They are supposed to be drawn horizontally for each category. I view it as-is on FF 9.0.1 Here is my code:

```
$(function () {
var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Count Per Category'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3', 'cat4', 'cat5'],
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Count',
                align: 'high'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [3, 4, 4, 3, 9]
        }]
    });
});
```

Kindly help me resolve this issue.

Comment: you seem to be missing some braces there. I tried this code out in jsfiddle and it works fine . http://jsfiddle.net/FtmZq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded to highchart version 2.2.1 form the previous 2.1.7 that I was using before and the graphs are rendering ok. Thanks for you input @Abhijith